# Postgres cumulative sum over earlier months

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has % of users for that month. I want to add those percents to get a cumulative sum up to that month. I don't think my cumulative function is right.

So, row 5 should show cum_amt 0.1381...
row 4,  0.1381 + 0.010169 = 0.148,
etc...

But row 1 should be 0.164 bc it is not bayside

[image]

```
select 
    created, name, new_users, possible, 
    (new_users::FLOAT / possible) as penetration,
    sum((new_users::FLOAT / possible)) OVER (ORDER BY created) AS cum_amt

from 
    mom_users

where 
    new_users > 10

order by
    name, created
    desc
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `partition by` and a division *after* the analytic function:

```
select created, name, new_users, possible, 
       (new_users::FLOAT / possible) as penetration,
       (sum(new_users::FLOAT) over (partition by name order by created) /
        sum(possible::FLOAT) over (partition by name order by created)
       ) as cum_amt

from mom_users
where new_users > 10
order byname, created desc;
```

Comment: close, but not quite the results. The starting month is right, but follow on months don't accumulate

Answer (score 0):

I think this code works for you.

```
CREATE TABLE mom_users (
created timestamp,
name text,
new_users int,
possible int
);

insert into mom_users values('2016-11-01 00:00:00', 'banning', 11, 67);
insert into mom_users values('2016-10-01 00:00:00', 'bayside', 253, 1180);
insert into mom_users values('2016-09-01 00:00:00', 'bayside', 92, 1180);
insert into mom_users values('2016-06-01 00:00:00', 'bayside', 12, 1180);
insert into mom_users values('2016-05-01 00:00:00', 'bayside', 163, 1180);

SELECT *, new_users/possible::real penetration, sum(new_users/possible::real) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY CREATED) cum_amt 
FROM mom_users 
WHERE new_users > 10
ORDER BY created DESC;
```